# Connect to Oracle DB 9i using SSH TUNNEL via putty

Tags: network, connectivity, oracle-9i

I am trying to connect to an Oracle database behind NAT. Therefore I create an ssh tunnel using putty.

This is the network  information:

- global IP example: 122.54.34.12
- LAN IP example: 192.168.3.103
- Oracle database port : 1521

and this is a snapshot of the putty ssh tunnel settings

[image]

After I have opened an ssh session  to the global IP with putty,
I try to connect to the Oracle database with SQL console through the ssh tunnel  but get the following error message:

```
sql > connect username/password@127.0.0.1/service-name
ERROR:
ORA-12170:TNS Connect timeout occurred
```

Comment: You need to create an entry in `tnsnames.ora` that points to localhost

Comment: Have you figured a solution? I have the same problem but I think it's because of the TNS redirect.

Answer (score 1):

If the global IP is the NAT running the ssh server and the LAN IP is the one with the Oracle server on it, then you need to use the LAN IP as the destination in the tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

You're close. Try the following instead:

```
connect username/password@//127.0.0.1/service-name
```

The double-slash is what's missing.

Comment: thnx for ur info ,but it does not work for me ??/